# EF Core, ignore Property connected to a Database-View, when saving

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 7. I have a Product class (and table) and I have a view. The view is configured to an entity (ViewAttribute) and one Product can have multiple ViewAttributes. This works well when I read from the database.

What doesn't work well is when I try to save the Product after an update. Since the ViewAttribute is a view. I want it to simply ignore the Attributes property, when I save. I get the error message that it tried to save 1 row, but saved 0.

1)
I can't use

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Ignore(p=> p.Attributes)
```

since I need the View-data when I read the Products.

2)
I have tried this, from another SO-post, but it doesn't seem to be for simple properties only, not for navigational (?)

```
// modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(e => e.Attributes)
//     .Metadata.SetBeforeSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
// modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(e => e.Attributes)
//    .Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
```

I get an error message in the startup that Attributes is a navigational property

3)
I have tried to set the Context.Entry(product.Attributes).State to Detached or Unmodified

I get an error message that the entity List does not exist in the modelling

4)
This

```
foreach (var att in ciItem.Attributes)
{
   Context.Entry(att).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
}
```

Just gives the original error message

5)
I have also tried
Context.Entry(product).Navigation("Attributes").IsModified = false;
Context.Entry(product).Navigation("Attributes").EntityEntry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;

The I get the error message
*'ViewAttribute' is not mapped to a table, therefore the entities cannot be persisted to the database*

**Details:**

```
public class Product
{
    public guid ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ViewAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class ViewAttribute
{
    public guid ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Different { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string TheView { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public DbSet<Product> Products => Set<Product>();
public DbSet<ViewAttribute> ViewAttributes => Set<ViewAttribut>();

modelBuilder.Entity<ProductAttribute>().ToView("ViewAttributes") 
    .HasKey(p => new { p.SomeId, p.SomeOtherId});
        
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>() 
            .HasMany(p => p.Attributes)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(av => av.ProductId);
```

It seems like the correct way would be (PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore), but I really can't get it to work and I don't really understand why

Comment: Have you tried to use EntityState.Detached instead of EntityState.Unchanged. Note you would again need to loop over "Attributes" collection.

Answer (score 0):

**[Accepted answer]** (I have to wait 2 days before I accept it with the green checkmark)

Ok, after some trial and error. A combination of 4 and 5 seems to work

If I set both the navigational property and each item to Unchanged, I can save the Product, and ignoring the Attributes

```
EntityEntry<T> result = DbSet.Update(item);
    
    if (item is CommercialItemBase ciItem)
    {
        Context.Entry(ciItem).Navigation("Attributes").EntityEntry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    
        foreach (var att in ciItem.Attributes)
        {
            Context.Entry(att).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
    }
```